# How to count number of present employees in each month?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.2

I am looking for SQL to count number of employees who were working in each month in that particular year. Means the result should be for QA department in year of 2013 like:

```
dept_name   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sept   Oct   Nov   Dec
QA          ( **count of working employees in each month** )
```

Table employee:

```
id    dept_id    emp_name    date_started     date_terminated
1     3          Amstrong    01-Apr-13        null
2     4          Blowing     03-Jun-13        null
3     3          Jerry       09-Sept-13       01-May-14
4     3          Smack       04-Jun-12        null
5     4          Zuckus      13-Aug-12        13-Dec-13
6     4          Kolman      19-Nov-12        null
7     3          Qual        15-Oct-12        02-Nov-13
8     4          John        11-Jul-11        06-Apr-13
9     4          Delta       28-Jan-14        null
10    3          Panther     17-Jul-14        null
11    3          Amay        01-Apr-13        null
12    4          Blue        03-Jun-13        null
13    3          Jack        09-Sept-13       01-May-14
14    3          Stack       04-Jun-12        null
15    4          Jasus       13-Aug-12        13-Dec-13
```

Table Department:

```
id      dept_name
1       IT
2       Support
3       QA
4       Development
5       Admin
```

Query that I tried to get result:

```
SELECT
    d.dept_name,
    COUNT (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.date_started) = 1 THEN e.id END) as "Jan",
    COUNT (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.date_started) = 2 THEN e.id END) as "Feb",
    COUNT (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.date_started) = 3 THEN e.id END) as "Mar",
    COUNT (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.date_started) = 4 THEN e.id END) as "Apr",
    COUNT (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.date_started) = 5 THEN e.id END) as "May",
    COUNT (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.date_started) = 6 THEN e.id END) as "Jun",
    COUNT (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.date_started) = 7 THEN e.id END) as "Jul",
    COUNT (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.date_started) = 8 THEN e.id END) as "Aug",
    COUNT (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.date_started) = 8 THEN e.id END) as "Sep",
    COUNT (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.date_started) = 10 THEN e.id END) as "Oct",
    COUNT (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.date_started) = 11 THEN e.id END) as "Nov",
    COUNT (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e.date_started) = 12 THEN e.id END) as "Dec"
FROM department d
    JOIN employee e ON (d.id = e.dept_id)
WHERE EXTRACT(month FROM e.date_started) BETWEEN 01 AND 12
    AND EXTRACT(year FROM e.date_started) < 2014
    AND (e.date_terminated IS NULL OR EXTRACT(month FROM e.date_terminated) > EXTRACT(month FROM NOW())) 
    AND (e.date_terminated IS NULL OR EXTRACT(year FROM e.date_terminated) >= EXTRACT(year FROM NOW()))
GROUP BY d.name
ORDER BY d.name ASC
```

But it consider only the employee who started to work in that particular month

Comment: You will necessary need to do a **stored procedure** to do something such precise.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?  Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: I didn't downvote because you *did* supply data and expected results ... but yes, you're ideally expected to attempt the problem yourself and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: Could you fix your tags? I see both [tag:PostgreSQL] as well as [tag:plsql]/[tag:plsqldeveloper] that are Oracle-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do it, this code will provide Jan and feb employee count for each department for 2013. Here it is in sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a861f/14

```
 SELECT a.dept_name, coalesce(Jan.total,0) as Jan, coalesce(Feb.total,0) as Feb
FROM department as a
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT dept_id, COUNT(emp_name) as total from employee
where date_started <= '2013-01-31 00:00:00'
and (date_terminated >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00' 
  or date_terminated is null) group by dept_id) as Jan
ON Jan.dept_id = a.id   
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT dept_id, COUNT(emp_name) as total from employee
where date_started <= '2013-02-31 00:00:00'
and (date_terminated >= '2013-02-01 00:00:00' 
  or date_terminated is null)  group by dept_id) as Feb
ON Feb.dept_id = a.id
```

Comment: your code is working but I need all departments list also to be there either null or zero

Comment: @codeBYmahesh Ok I updated the answer to reflect that shows all departments and a zero :)

Comment: Thanks, Its working but not optimized even am accepting this answer

Answer (score 1):

You should have a column in your table like a LOG then you could truly check who was working in a given month, at the moment it is not posible to check who was working which month you can only check how many employes started in a given month or how many employees ended working in a given month.

But thats how the query should look only in the WHERE you would have to add a new employee column that stores a log of present employees at work.....

```
SELECT

COUNT(employee.id) as 'Number of EMployees',
department.dept_name as 'Department name'

FROM employee

LEFT JOIN department on employee.dept_id=department.id

WHERE 

employee.dateLog > 2013-01-01
employee.dateLog < 2013-02-01
```

Comment: It is still possible to count the number of employees working in a given month, by looking at the start and stop range...

Comment: Well not really...all you need is just to add Log column.....or even a separate table all together. Because if you will try to count number of users based on the information you have in your current table it will not tell you how many employees worked in this month but how many employees started or finished the job......

Comment: look here and implement your code WHERE 

employee.dateLog > 2013-01-01
employee.dateLog < 2013-02-01

Comment: @boomoto This will never give you true number of how many people were working in a given month only how many people started/finished work........If there is a wide outspread of Eboly virus and most of employes dont come in to work your result number will be wrong....I know that is extreme but it is better to learn structure database propley for any situation so the numbers values are wright

Comment: @ZiomekZiomski, he might only have read-only access, yes its poorly design but that's not the question. My way works he wants the number of employees employed in a given month not the amount worked. If your sick your still employed.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a date in each month and find the number of employees who work on that date.  The format will have one row per department per month.  Pivoting the results in a separate operation, perhaps better done at the application layer:

```
with months as (
      select generate_series('2013-01-01'::timestamp, '2013-12-01'::timestamp, '1 month') as m
     ),
select d.dept_name, m.m, count(e.dept_id) as numemployees
from department d cross join
     months m left join
     employee e
     on e.dept_id = d.id and e.date_started <= m.m and
        (e.date_terminated is null or e.date_terminated >= m.m)
group by d.dept_name, m.m
order by d.dept_name, m.m;
```